# Trying to install Ant but getting -bash: brew: command not found

Tags: bash, homebrew, path

I have installed Homebrew using the code

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL   https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

it returns this inside the Terminal window

```
==> This script will install:
/usr/local/bin/brew
/usr/local/Library/...
/usr/local/share/man/man1/brew.1
==> The following directories will be made group writable:
/usr/local/.
/usr/local/bin
/usr/local/include
/usr/local/lib
/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig
/usr/local/share
/usr/local/share/man
==> The following directories will have their owner set to mitchellgant:
/usr/local/.
/usr/local/bin
/usr/local/include
/usr/local/lib
/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig
/usr/local/share
/usr/local/share/man
==> The following directories will have their group set to admin:
/usr/local/.
/usr/local/bin
/usr/local/include
/usr/local/lib
/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig
/usr/local/share
/usr/local/share/man
```

and then I tried all of the following

```
brew doctor
brew update
brew install ant
```

Each yields back the line

```
-bash: brew: command not found
```

In some other questions similar to mine, some people suggested changing the path but I'm not exactly sure how to do that.
Running `echo $PATH` yields `/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin` but I don't know how to change it or if it should be changed in the first place. Any assistance or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What's your OS X version?

Answer (score 1):

If `brew doctor` doesn't run, then you have some breakage in the PATH variable on the system or you need to re-run the installer package, perhaps cleaning up things according to the [support site for homebrew](http://brew.sh).

You can check where the brew command is with:

```
which brew
type brew
```

Both of those should point to a command located at: `/usr/local/bin/brew` and the path `/usr/local/bin` should be in your path variable. To test that, quit terminal and open a new window. The set command below should look like the one I pasted with "mac" and "me" different for you in all likelihood.

```
mac:~ me$ set | grep -i PATH
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

Since this is how the system should be set up out of the box, if you have made modifications you'll want to look over the site for ways to debug a broken path. Your text seems to indicate that the path is set correctly, but that's the cause of command not found or the brew script itself is somehow corrupted - but that script is in `/bin/sh` not `bash` so I would expect a different error if it's messed up in some manner.